# why does 'new' allocated array has garbage value?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>


void main()
{

    char* str3 = "Underworld";

    int str_length = strlen(str3);
    char* str_context = new char[str_length];
    for (int i = 0; i != str_length; i++) {
        str_context[i] = str3[i];
    }
        std::cout << str3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << str_context << std::endl;
    
}
```

i expected `cout << str_context` prints out UnderWorld

however, str_context cout prints out `Underworld金蘇--`

why does str_context have garbage value even if i limited size of array by `new char[str_length}` ?

str3 cout prints out "Underworld" though

Comment: `strlen` returns the length of the string, which does not include the null terminator. When you copy the contents of `str3` into `str_context`, you don't copy that null terminator. Then, when you pass a non-null-terminated character array to `<<`, you end up with undefined behavior.

Comment: even if a duplicated question your answer made me clear
have a great day

Comment: Also note in current C++ you should avoid new/delete whenever you can (your current code is very "C" like), in this case just use `std::string` (instead of new char).  `std::string str3{"underworld"}; std::string context{str3};`  context will be copy constructed for you (initialized with a copy of str3). `std::size_t str_length = str.size();` will get the size of the str3 for you.

Comment: And if you must use C strings in C++, note that you should have used `strdup()` instead of all this manual coding.